# Killing a subprocess in python in a proper way

Tags: python

right now I've got a little problem: I call a script with subprocess.Popen() that changes the behaviour of some hardware I use.

Now when I want to shut it down with the Popen.Kill() command, the hardware isnt resetting its behaviour. Instead it just has the same. But I want the hardware to reset.

Is there any way to tell the the python script I call with popen, to do some things before it gets killed with the Popen.Kill() command.

Example:

Current Behaviour:

```
Hardware does send.
hardware_process.kill()
Hardware does still send
```

But what I wish:

```
Hardware does send.
hardware_process.kill()
Hardware does not send anymore.
```

Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: subprocess.kill() kills with SIGTERM. You cannot intercept that. you could send a message. or on Linux, use `os.kill(SIGQUIT)` (not sure of the syntax) and catch the signal from your other program side.

Comment: Could you give a code example

Comment: can't you run another script which changes back the hardware state like before?